# Codeigniter: using libraries in controller?

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I want use my library function in controller file. Is it possible ? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. If by that you mean "Can I write my own libraries and call them from a controller in CodeIgniter", the answer is yes.

I suggest take a look at [this page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) in the CodeIgniter documentation for further details.